# Can a derived class's member function behavior be determined by which class it is instantiated by?

Tags: c++, inheritance, virtual-inheritance

The classes Rectangle and Triangle are both derived from Shape. I want to add another class ComplexShape, which can be any specific shape with other shapes attached to it.

I know there are easy workarounds for this problem, like declaring a variable to store shape properties in the base class, but I'm more interested in ways to adress the title question. How do I, if possible, define the constructor of ComplexShape, so that ComplexShape uses the methods of the class used to initialize it?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <memory>
#include <vector>

class Shape {
    public: virtual unsigned int getPointCount() const = 0;
};

class Rectangle : public Shape {
    public: unsigned int getPointCount() const { return 4; }
};

class Triangle : public Shape {
    public: unsigned int getPointCount() const { return 3; }
};

class ComplexShape : public Shape {
public:
    std::vector<std::shared_ptr<Shape>> children;

    //What Constructor comes here?

    unsigned int getPointCount() const {
        unsigned int i{ 0u };
        for(auto shape : children) i += shape->getPointCount();
        return i;
    }
};

int main() {
    Triangle triangle();
    ComplexShape arrow; //How do I initialize this as a rectangle?
    arrow.children.push_back(std::shared_ptr<Shape>(new Triangle()));
    std::cout << arrow.getPointCount();
    return 0;
};
```

Comment: You state that a complex shape is a collection of shapes, why not implement it like that? I don't see the need to "promote" one of the shapes as the "base" shape like you ask.

Comment: To answer the question in the title: I think no. You could implement it as a template, then you have a strongly typed member to refer to the "main" shape. (I'm a C# dev, apologies if my wording is incorrect. I'm referring to C# generics)

Comment: Search **Composite pattern**, it will give you an idea how to implement it. By the way, your variable ˋchildren` should be private. As indicated in other comments, it would probably be better if the "main" shape is inside the child list.

Comment: Whoops, I realized I messed up. ComplexShape::getPointCount should not just be the points of the children, but of the parent as well. This made me realize that since ComplexShape::getPointCount is different from Rectangle::getPointCount, it wouldn't make sense to have the ComplexShape be a Rectangle. I was just being too closed-minded.

Comment: `Triangle triangle();` Where is that triangle function defined?

Answer (score 0):

You could try with initializer list used in constructor: http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/initializer_list/initializer_list/

```
#include <iostream>
#include <memory>
#include <vector>
#include <initializer_list>

class Shape {
public: virtual unsigned int getPointCount() const = 0;
};

class Rectangle : public Shape {
public: unsigned int getPointCount() const { return 4; }
};

class Triangle : public Shape {
public: unsigned int getPointCount() const { return 3; }
};

class ComplexShape : public Shape {
public:
    std::vector<std::shared_ptr<Shape>> children;
    ComplexShape() {}

    ComplexShape(std::initializer_list<std::shared_ptr<Shape>> init) : children(init)
    {
        // do some dynamic_cast magic here
    }

    unsigned int getPointCount() const {
        unsigned int i{ 0u };
        for (auto shape : children) i += shape->getPointCount();
        return i;
    }
};

int main() {
    Triangle triangle();
    ComplexShape arrow; //How do I initialize this as a rectangle?
    arrow.children.push_back(std::shared_ptr<Shape>(new Triangle()));
    std::cout << arrow.getPointCount();

    // This could be simplified probably
    ComplexShape rect = { std::shared_ptr<Shape>(new Triangle()), std::shared_ptr<Shape>(new Triangle()) };
    return 0;
};
```